# Clarification on the Premises of the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen Argument

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, eigenvalue, quantum-states, epr-experiment

In their famous [EPR paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.47.777), Einstein, Podolsky and Rosen argue that quantum mechanics does not provide a complete description of physical reality. To do this, they make two key assumptions:

1. in a complete theory, every element of physical reality must have a corresponding element in the theory
2. if we can predict with certainty (i.e. with probability 1) the value of a physical quantity of some system without disturbing that system, then there must exist an element of physical reality corresponding to that physical quantity

The authors stress that the second condition is taken to be a sufficient condition for the reality of a physical quantity but that it need not be a necessary one. It is claimed that this is in agreement with classical and quantum mechanical ideas of reality. However, supposing that a complete theory exists, then for the condition to not be necessary for the reality of a physical quantity, it must, according to the first assumption, be possible for an element of physical reality to have a corresponding physical quantity in the complete theory but for it not to be possible to predict with certainty the value of this quantity from the theory without disturbing the system.

It appears to me then that according to the usual quantum mechanical idea of reality, the condition would in fact be necessary for the reality of a physical quantity. Indeed, later in the paper, the authors do appear to take the condition to be necessary for the physical reality of a quantity in quantum mechanics when they use the fact that no quantum state can be a simultaneous eigenstate of the position and momentum operators to claim that the position of a particle with known momentum has no physical reality.

Is it true that the usual quantum mechanical idea of reality takes the given condition as sufficient but not necessary for the physical reality of some quantity? If so, how does the argument that the position of a particle with definite momentum has no physical reality follow?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. To make your question more readable, you may want to split long sentences into shorter ones. Also, separate the large paragraph into multiple paragraphs, and make sure that it is clear what your main question is.

Comment: Related reference paper: [Bell, 1975](https://inspirehep.net/literature/99498)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "supposing that a complete theory exists, then for the condition to not be necessary for the reality of a physical quantity, it must, according to the first assumption, be possible for an element of physical reality to have a corresponding physical quantity in the complete theory but for it not to be possible to predict with certainty the value of this quantity from the theory without disturbing the system."

Yes. One way this could be is when the complete theory is like classical theory with random variables; there is a property of the system that we regard as element of reality, so it has representation in the theory, but nothing else in that theory determines its value. For example, a random variable like fluctuating electric field acting on the charged particles in the system. We know it is there, it is element of reality, but nothing else in the theory determines its value, it is an independent quantity.

> It appears to me then that according the classical and quantum mechanical ideas of reality, the condition would in fact be necessary for the reality of a physical quantity.

Some people would regard the condition as necessary for quantity being real (the Copenhagen interpretation, a kind of scientific positivism based on rejection of classical physics thinking), others don't (EPR, statistical interpretation, an extension of classical physics thinking). Unfortunately, there is no agreed upon concept of what is / is not an element of reality. The Copenhagen school usually admits only those quantities as really existing that can be predicted, not created via measurement, with 100% success, EPR simply assume there are such things regardless of our predictive abilities and they have some properties (independence of people thoughts, intentions, abilities, distant events like measurements etc.)

> "later in the paper, the authors do appear to take the condition to be necessary for the physical reality of a quantity in quantum mechanics when they use the fact that no quantum state can be a simultaneous eigenstate of the position and momentum operators to claim that the position of a particle with known momentum has no physical reality."

If you mean the EPR text after formula (6), I don't think authors mean what you describe. The text there becomes somewhat incoherent and harder to follow, but I think what they are saying is that *usually in quantum theory expositions*, the mathematical fact that no eigenfunction of $p$ can be also eigenfunction of $x$, is believed to imply that when state is that describe by eigenfunction of $p$, position $x$ cannot be an element of reality.

EPR do not believe this is necessarily correct, because they have a different conception of what is real than the usual quantum theory expositions. They suspect non-commuting quantities can be simultaneously real, which would be possible if quantum theory was not complete. Which is a possibility the usual expositions did not discuss. They propose this stance in the EPR paper and defend it by trying to show there are elements of reality (because predictable with 100% success) not captured by the quantum theory.

> Is it true that the usual quantum mechanical idea of reality takes the given condition as sufficient but not necessary for the physical reality of some quantity?

The usual used to be the Copenhagen stance described above, so it used to be "yes it is necessary" or "don't talk about real, talk about predictions and measurements". As decades passed, with help of Bohm and Bell and others, people got more open to EPR thinking and we got also "it is sufficient, but there are other possibilities, maybe there are real things for which we just don't have the best theory". Nowadays there are other viewpoints on what is real as well, such as the pretty absurd Everett theory, where the real thing is the psi function of the Universe with large number of arguments and our observations and measurements are just a random subset of properties of this extremely complicated mathematical object.

Comment: Am I right in thinking then that the EPR argument is only an argument that quantum mechanics with the Copenhagen interpretation is an incomplete theory? The argument rests on the claim that either quantum mechanics is incomplete or two quantities represented by non-commuting operators can't have simultaneous reality. If we say, for example, that a particle with known momentum has a real position but that this position can't be determined (like the electric field in the example you gave) and is represented by the position space wavefunction, is this not consistent with both of the assumptions?

Comment: > "*only an argument that quantum mechanics with the Copenhagen interpretation is an incomplete theory?"* -- That is the main EPR *claim*. The argument is explained in the paper on few pages. It has some problems, such as assuming two things are simultaneous elements of reality because we can choose which one to predict with 100% success, but we can't do this for both. Thus the pair does not strictly obey the sufficiency condition defined earlier (authors address this problem at the end, but not everybody will find it convincing).

Comment: > *"...is this not consistent with both of the assumptions?"* -- Which assumptions do you mean? Certainly it is not consistent with the assumption that "quantities represented by non-commuting operators can't have simultaneous reality".

Comment: By the assumptions, I mean the completeness criterion and the sufficient condition for the reality of a quantity. In the example of a particle with known momentum, the position would be represented in the theory (in the form of the position space wavefunction), thereby being consistent with the claim that quantum mechanics is complete, the claim that the position of the particle is real and the completeness criterion. Moreover, there is no contradiction with the sufficient condition for the reality of the particle since this is only a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: Hence, it seems that the claim that either quantum mechanics is incomplete or two quantities represented by non-commuting operators can't have simultaneous reality does not follow from the assumptions, unless we insist that the possibility of predicting with certainty the position of the particle is a necessary condition for its reality. Why can the position of the particle not be like the fluctuating electric field you gave as an example before? In other words, could it not be that QM is a complete theory and that the position of the particle is real but it cannot be determined?

Comment: Given that the rest of the argument depends on the claim that either quantum mechanics is incomplete or it is impossible for two quantities represented by two non-commuting variables to have simultaneous reality, it would seem that the authors are only arguing against the completeness of a version of quantum mechanics which insists that the possibility of predicting the value of a quantity with certainty is a necessary condition for its reality, e.g. the Copenhagen interpretation. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: > *"In the example of a particle with known momentum, the position would be represented in the theory (in the form of the position space wavefunction), thereby being consistent with the claim that quantum mechanics is complete"* -- The psi function of coordinates *is not* a counterpart of the element of reality (position of the particle). It is description of probabilities of coordinates, but not counterpart of single  triplet of coordinates. We could introduce some formula that would provide this counterpart based on the psi function, but then the resulting theory is no longer quantum theory.

Comment: I don't see how considering the psi function as a counterpart to the real position of the particle and treating the position as a random variable with a given distribution is different to treating the fluctuating electric field as a random variable in the classical example you gave previously. In the case of the electric field, it seems we were happy to say that the electric field was real and had a counterpart in the theory, even though the complete theory did not determine the value of the field. Is there an important difference between these two examples?

Comment: If the counterpart in the complete theory to every real physical quantity has to be the value of that quantity, then surely the necessity of being able to predict with certainty the value of every real physical quantity would follow automatically? It seems like a tautology.

Comment: The kind of theory you suggest is indeed similar to my example of fluctuating electric field. It can push the resulting theory towards completeness. But it also pushes it away from quantum theory. It has something that quantum theory does not have - a random variable corresponding to position of the particle. I think Bohm's theory is like this. Position of single particle exists there always, irrespective of how psi function looks like. But this theory is not standard quantum theory, it is a development/modification of it.

Comment: > *"If the counterpart in the complete theory to every real physical quantity has to be the value of that quantity, then surely the necessity of being able to predict with certainty the value of every real physical quantity would follow automatically?"* -- Definitely not. The quantity may be in theory, it may have value, but the value may remain unknown. Like when it is random variable of known probability distribution.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to summarise my current understanding. The EPR paper claims that any quantum mechanical theory which insists that the values of all real physical quantities must be determined by the theory is incomplete. However, you can create versions of quantum mechanics in which quantities represented by non-commuting operators can have simultaneous reality. The values of these are unknown (due to the uncertainty principle) and are represented in the theory as random variables. The EPR paper does not claim that these theories are incomplete. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I think that is almost right, except 1) there is really only one "quantum theory" discussed in the EPR paper - the standard rules for psi functions and operators plus the collapse postulate. And *this* scheme is judged incomplete. While there can be *extensions/modifications* of this scheme where we have more concepts in the scheme allowing for simultaneous values of quantities like $x,p_x$. Later after the EPR paper these extensions got named "local hidden variable theories"; local because of the EPR requirement that reality of system I isn't changed by measurement of system II.